# Return array of arrays as response from query in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working with a query in mongoose as below:

```
return await this.model.find({ lastname: req.lastname})
```

(lastname is a field in my collection)

Everything works fine, but I need a way to get the data from the query in this kind of structure:

[ [data], [data] ...., [data]]

Currently I am getting this kind of response: [ {data}, {data}....., {data}].

Comment: if you can give sample data from the database, and what data you want to get with the query.  check also if you can `$objectToArray` operator maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. First of all, what you are doing is simply getting the result in **default format**.
In order to get the solution in your required format,

```
Use array, $push and $each.

**Array:** First, make sure that you create a result array 
let result = [];//create an array 
result = await db.find({filter}.$push({$each()});
```